# How to show my only Blog Who related with tags

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i am using This package for tag my blog my Laravel 5.2 App

```
https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-taggable
```

now i want to show only that blog who related with tag
i am trying to do like this here is my route.php

```
Route::get('blog/category/{category}', [
'uses'  =>  'BlogController@categoryindex',
'as'    =>  'category.index'
]);
```

Here is my controller

```
public function categoryindex($slug){

    $blogs = blog::where('normalized', $slug)->withAnyTags();

    return view('blog.categoryindex', compact('blogs'));

}
```

Here is my blog.categoryindex.blade.php

```
@foreach($blogs as $blog)
    <h1>{{ $blog->title }}</h1>
@endforeach
```

but its won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this package - nor have I tested, but based on the documentation, I think you're looking for this:

```
$blogs = Blog::withAnyTags($slug)->get(); //this is correct

@foreach($blogs as $blog)
    <h1>{{ $blog->title }}</h1>
@endforeach
```

***It'd be helpful is you `dd($blogs)` and show me the result.***

Comment: i try dd($blogs);
its show me null
something problem to my controller

$blogs = blog::where('normalized', $slug)->withAnyTags();

i don't have normalized column on my blog table its on taggable table i don't have table model
i am using trait

Comment: just `return dd($blogs);` in your controller...versus returning the view.

Comment: Might want to try this instead `blog::withAnyTags()->where('normalized', $slug);`

Comment: here is my return dump when i try blog::withAnyTags()->where('normalized', $slug);

Comment: That's your issue then. `blog::` should be capitalized FYI. and add `->get()` to the end of the query. So: `Blog::withAnyTags()->where('normalized', $slug)->get();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116735/discussion-between-sid-heart-and-mike-barwick).

Comment: What does `dd($blog)` output?

Comment: Meaning, do `dd(Blog::withAnyTags());` Show me this result.

Comment: Yes i recieve my all blog post but all

Comment: Show me result. I.e. The response object

Comment: i posted my response

Comment: Thank you mate its fix and i found the sollution
public function categoryindex($slug){

        $blogs = Blog::withAnyTags($slug)->get();
        
        return view('blog.categoryindex', compact('blogs'));

    }